# Android | Why do activity look different on two different phones with same resolution as well as same screen size?

Tags: android, responsive-design, dpi, android-resolution, ppi

**Scenario**

I am developing a random app and recently i encountered a problem. I run a same application on Google pixel 3a xl android emulator and Asus X00TD physical device. And I got to know that in asus phone UI got really changed.

Pixel 3a XL display specs :

Display size :  6.0 inch
Resolution   :  2160 × 1080
ppi          :  402ppi

Asus X00TD display specs :

Display size : 6.0 inch
Resolution   : 2160 × 1080
ppi          : 403ppi

You see It's almost same only ppi is different and i don't think so that will make some big difference. roughly 6 pixels will be affected and that's not gonna change whole UI. I don't know the `dpi` resolution of the asus x00td. And I can't find on internet too.

This is the UI difference between pixel 3a xl and asus x00td.

[image: 6.0 inch mobile comparision]

As you can see there's big difference between emulator and physical phone. So, I have 2 questions

1. There's a way to calculate dpi by function. but, What if I don't have a phone and still want to know dpi res of that phone?
2. Why there is a big difference between emulator and physical phone?

**EDIT**

I tried to calculate it on internet but, it gave me `0.0631mm` dot pitch. which i am not able to understant what it is. Also emulator shows that pixel 3a xl has `400dpi` resolution.

So, What is difference between `400dpi` and `0.0631mm dot pitch`?

**SOLUTION I TRIED**

I tried to emulate the asus device in emulator by setting smallest width to 360dp. Initially it looked same as asus. and emulator was picking `xhdpi` file of `dimens.xml`. So, I made changes in `dimens.xml` of `xhdpi` but, asus didn't pick that file. instead it picked `xxhdpi` file. Which is used in another device Realme 3 pro. I can't modify `xxhdpi` file because it's gonna mess up UI for all the 6+ inch display phones. and at the same time asus is still picking `xxhdpi` file and asus's UI is messed up.

Can't find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained upper by snachmsm, Layout qualifiers are most helpful in acheiving display responsiveness.

In my case it was the asus x00td which wasn't displaying the content correctly. SO, to fix that,

I used `height` qualifier value of`height` which resulted in minimum height.. So, devices with height of `600dp` or above will be using `dimens.xml(h600dp)`. So, asus picked up this file. As well as I created file for `700dp` as well which has slighly bigger dimensions for large display like realme 3 pro.

Plus I used constraint layout guidelines percentages to rearrange views in manner that margins will be adjusted automatically.

So, dimensions and sizes are controlled by dimens.xml and margins are automatically controlled by constraint layout.

Answer (score 1):

these differences are caused by different density bucket set for these devices by manufacturers. from [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp):

> **xhdpi**     Resources for extra-high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

> **xxhdpi**    Resources for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi) screens (~480dpi).

note that you are somewhere in the middle of these values. looks like Asus decided to configure own Android as `xxhdpi`, so interface scales up to bigger UI elements (also uses bigger images), while Google set up `xhdpi` qualifier making own interface "more packable" with smaller UI elements and icons

under density qualifiers you can keep e.g. `dimen`, so size of margins or thickness of some lines or borders. Especially when you are using many resources with `@android`/`android.R` prefix, built into system - these are oftenly highly parametrized depending on bucket, e.g. thick list items separator may have `0` height value on `ldpi` devices for hidding it out leaving more space for content on such small/poor screen. also different images/drawables are used to draw. put a red dot on icon in top right corner, but only in `xxhdpi` folder and you will see that only one device will get this change

also there is an option in developer settings for manipulating "max width", in there you can "change density" and can try how interface of whole system and apps change. bet on Asus is set to ~360 when on Pixel is set to at least 400 (rounding up to xx bucket, as closer to 480)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your advise. I have been looking for the answer for a week. And with your help I got clue. I tested and found asus is picking up ```xxhdpi``` file instead ```xhdpi```.But, I have another device realme 3 pro with 6.3 inch display which also picks ```xxhdpi```. If i set dimensions according to asus, realme 3 pro shows everything with too much space. Means dimensions are too small for realme 3 pro. Any idea how I can create a file for devices like asus?

Comment: maybe using different "kind" of density bucket will satisfy you - use smallest width like [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseSWQuali). e.g. `values-sw600dp` folder = resources used for devices with at least 600dp of smallest width (so width or height)